VisualForce apex markup code to open salesforce report using its name
I am having scenario where salesforce tabular report needs to be opened using the report's name(and not id) through VF Markup. I have tried the following in VisualForce Markup and a new page opens but doesn't display the report. Any help on what I could be doing wrong? I appreciate it!
<apex:page>
<script>
Report rep = [Select Id from Report where Name = 'Employee Info' LIMIT 1];
Id repId = rep.Id;

var URL = '/'+repId;
var win = window.open(URL,"target=_blank");
window.history.back();

</script>
</apex:page>

** attempt with remoting code:
<apex:page >
    <apex:remoteObjects >
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Report" fields="Id" />
    </apex:remoteObjects>
    <script>
    let report = new SObjectModel.Report();
    report.retrieve(
      function() {
        return { where: { Name: { eq: "Driver Information" } } }
      },
      function(err, records) {
        window.open('/${records[0].get("Id")}', "_blank");
        window.history.back();
      });
    </script>
</apex:page>


You can't run Apex code directly in a Visualforce page. You'd need to create a controller class first.
public class ReportWindowController {
  public String getRecordId() {
    return [SELECT Id FROM Report WHERE Name = 'Employee Info' LIMIT 1].Id;
  }
}

Which you can then reference in your Visualforce code:
<apex:page controller="ReportWindowController">
  <script>
    window.open("{!'/'+recordId}","_blank");
    window.history.back();
  </script>
</apex:page>

However, this is something you can actually do just by using Visualforce remoting:
<apex:page >
    <apex:remoteObjects >
        <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Report" fields="Id" />
    </apex:remoteObjects>
    <script>
    let report = new SObjectModel.Report();
    report.retrieve(
      function() {
        return { where: { Name: { eq: "Employee Info" } } }
      },
      function(err, records) {
        window.open(`/${records[0].get("Id")}`, "_blank");
        window.history.back();
      });
    </script>
</apex:page>

This requires more Visualforce, but doesn't require any Apex, so you don't need to worry about unit testing, either writing tests or during deployment.
Note that popup blockers may block automated opens, so you may want to present a link or button for the user to use.

Thank you for the response. Can this be achieved just with the visualforce code ? (without worrying about the apex class controller). I tried keeping the visualforce remoting code and didn't work for me.

I would like to explore just the VF markup code if possible. can record id be set directly in visualforce code ? I tried using the remoting code and it throws error saying 'page doesn't exist - enter a valid url and try again'. thanks!

@bibar Yes, the last example in my answer comes directly from my dev org, with just the report name changed. It sounds like something went wrong with your code. Can you edit your question to include your attempt? I'll be happy to review.

I have edited the question to include my attempt. The report name I am using is 'Driver Information'(under the section : ** attempt with remoting code) . Could you please review ?

@bibar I see your problem. The line where you used window.open, I used a template literal, but you used normal quotes. The template literal can use merge fields, which I find easier to read than regular string concatenation. Read my code again, noting how the highlight is different. Fix that, and it should work.

I tried that too . It opens a new page with this URL : mysalesforce--c.sandbox.vf.force.com/apex/Employee_Info and it is a blank page. Should the URL when opened in a new page be like : mysalesforce.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Report/00OReportId ? My popup is enabled too.

@bibar You'll have to check your browser's Developer Console (typically F12). You may have an error that's preventing from working.

This is the error : Unload event listeners are deprecated and will be removed.
1 source
VFRemote.js:32

@bibar That shouldn't stop the page from working. Also, I don't get that error. What browser and OS are you on?

I am using google chrome and operating system , windows 10 pro

@bibar Okay, a quick research shows that they plan on removing unload in the coming years. As such, someone at Salesforce should probably be notified about this situation before it becomes more dire. For now, I'd say just use the Apex and be done with it.
